# Can reactor.connectTCP occur after reactor.run in twisted python?

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.internet

I wish to add more protocols and factories after reactor runs. I couldn't find documentation which says this is allowed. When I make reactor.run before reactor.connectTCP, the program hangs around buildProtocol in factory. Is it possible to add reactor.connectTCP to the reactor after reactor.run?

Answer (score 7):

Yes, you can start or stop listening on a TCP port at any time in Twisted.  However, code like

```
reactor.run()
reactor.listenTCP(...)
```

won't work because `run()` only returns when the reactor has been stopped and the program is ready to exit.  So you need to call `listenTCP` in response to something.

Also, don't use `listenTCP` directly; it's a very low-level API.  Instead, use [Endpoints](https://twistedmatrix.com/documents/15.3.0/core/howto/endpoints.html).