# Twisted : Running listening reactor.listenTCP or connectTCP() after Run()

Tags: python, python-2.7, network-programming, twisted

I am writing an application using the Twisted framework, it needs to be able to call connectTCTP() or listenTCP() after reactor.run().

First question: Is this possible?

Second question: Is it an acceptable paradigm for Twisted usage.

I found one question on this [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32014198/can-reactor-connecttcp-occur-after-reactor-run-in-twisted-python), unfortunately doesn't give an answer.

**Clarification**

I am running a server that listens on 8001, but also connecting to two other servers.  I won't be starting connecting until after the reactor has started (as the exact hostnames won't be known until received from the listening socket.

Main Loop:

```
def MainLoop(self):

    reactor.run()
```

In the setup function (after XML file has been read):

```
    while networkConnsOpen == False:

        if self.__gatewayInterfaceUp == False:
            reactor.listenTCP(8000, GatewayInterfaceFactory())
            self.__gatewayInterfaceUp = True

        reactor.connectTCP("localhost", 9001, ListFactory())
```

Comment: It seems to me that it does give an answer.  It says "Yes, you can start or stop listening on a TCP port at any time in Twisted."  What else are  you looking for?

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Yes, but I am listening/connecting using multiple factories from the same factory, won't that drop all of the other connections?

Comment: Uh ... no?  That seems like an entirely different question to me.  If there is some connection here, I don't see it.  Maybe you could clarify your question some some further details, perhaps some example code.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone Added clarification.  Could I start and stop End points instead of the entire reactor?

Comment: You shouldn't have a "main loop" in your code.  That's what Twisted is for.  You might want to read something like http://krondo.com/an-introduction-to-asynchronous-programming-and-twisted/ to get a general sense of how Twisted works.

Comment: If I was to stop and restart a reactor would that drop any open connections?

Comment: You can't restart the reactor.  I no longer have any clear idea what your question is.  It may be an XY problem or it may just not be a good fit for stackoverflow.  You might want to try getting some interactive help on #twisted on freenode.

Comment: @Jean-PaulCalderone I pieced together an answer after re-reading your comments.  Thank you.